# I can't see messages of enemy players in chat (War Thunder)

Tags: war-thunder

I have been playing War Thunder for a few years with no problem. But more recently, I started watching Youtube videos of WT gameplay, as well as started playing more custom battles. Something I see on Youtube videos is a few enemy players using the [All] chat feature, and their messages are visible. 
  But when I play, I see none, even in custom battles, where enemies talking to both teams in chat is very common. I can tell that enemies *are* using chat with both teams because I see many "ghost conversations", where my teammates answer questions and reply to nothing (I can see) in chat. Here is an example of a "ghost conversation" I saw:

(**Teammate**)> hey (**Enemy Player**) I like ur skin

(**Teammate**)> you custom made that? what program did you use?

(**Teammate**)> ok thanks, i'm getting it now

{*comes back with new skin*}

(**Teammate**)> you like?

(**Teammate**)> thx

(**Teammate**)> oh ok bye

This is from a custom match, and the messages were uninterrupted by any messages in between. I have no problem viewing teammates' messages.

Edit: When I first got the game I could see enemy chat messages. That was on an older computer, but this glitch started on that computer after about a half-year break from the game and carried on to this newer computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a feature added (in 2014, IIRC) which allowes to control what you can see in chat and defaults to "Team and Squad" setting. You can find it under options -> interface -> chat messages. Set it to "All" to see enemy messages.